# Client(android application) acks for sent gcm messages

Tags: android, push-notification, xmpp, real-time, google-cloud-messaging

Can the android app get the acknowledgements for the sent gcm messages via googleclougmessaging.send() to ccs servers ? How can the client be sure about the delivery of the message to the ccs server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Cloud Connection Server docs, the only acknowledgment when sending a message from device to cloud is the acknowledgment expected by the Cloud Connection Server from your server. It only tells CCS that your server got the message, but CCS doesn't pass that acknowledgment to the device.

> Here is the format of the ACK expected by CCS from 3rd-party app
>   servers in response to the above message:
>
> ```
> <message id="">
>   <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
>       {
>           "to":"REGID",
>           "message_id":"m-123"
>           "message_type":"ack"
>       } 
>   </gcm>
> </message>
> ```

Of course, your server can send a message back to the device as a response to the message it got from the device, and that message can serve as an acknowledgment.

Answer (score 1):

I face many problems with Gcm Acks, so the solution for you is to do that by yourself, it's very sample:

1. when xmpp reciev any message you should write a function  to send ack to the sender (via GCM) with any data you want. and when the sender device get that ack (lets call it ("fromxmppAck") you can deal with it as ack for everything.
2. when the target device get any message, you should write a function to send ack to the xmpp tells that the message is received on the target device, (call it: from_target_ack)
3. When the server get "from_target_ack" (it must contain the ID of the original sender) just pass the message to the original sender...
4. in the original sender you should deal with this ack knowing that the message arrived to the target.

this what I did when I force problems with GCM Acks, I just ignore gcm acks and did 1. 2. 3. 4. and everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

As I know from my experience gcm sends back ack to the device... the ack message type is "send event" and it contains : 1.message id 2. event.. The event faild describes the  result of sending msg.

Comment: Only when any error on message send is happend the event occurs. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html. There is no event available as sent message. If there is no error in sending, we can take it as success sent.

Comment: have you try it? the documentation of android is so bad..I use this message type in my application...gcm sends back ack when it receive ur message, and u can configure it to tell the 3rd party server if the target device got the message.

Comment: I was asking about the acks to android application when it sends a message not about the xmpp client ?

Comment: when you send message from device to GCM, the GCM return to you(the device) an Ack: message_type =  send_event , 
 event =  sent , 
google.message_id =  35216806074292010:21:38 <<< this is the sent message ID.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#getMessageType%28android.content.Intent%29

Comment: OK Dear, I don't Like to argue, But Trying is stronger than books, they (Android | google ) develop thier srvice but they don't update the  documentations in the same frequency..
In the page you point there are 3 types of message, but in practice you can see 4th one (( E/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ message_type =  send_event))<<this come to the device from GCM..