# Having trouble with sending a notification again to sender for acknowledgement in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am new in android and I am working on a android project in which sending notification is the feature of that project. Every thing works fine notification have successfully send and receive when user receive the notification its open a dialog. In a dialog there are two option accept or reject when user accept it send the acknowledgement to user but acknowledgement receive on receiver device instead of sender device. I think its a issue of reg id

Have a look on my code

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
static String regid;
CheckBox isdriver;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
String user_name = "";
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
String TAG = "MainActivity";
String SENDER_ID = "224163385438";
String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCL3REK_ONEgLdhcP8giso_5P6xWE3gUvA";
static Utils utils;
private Context context = MainActivity.this;
private ProgressDialog pb;
private EditText username;
String sender_regid;
private ArrayList<PeopleObject> peopleObjList;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    BookingActivity book = new BookingActivity();
    registerReceiver(book.broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    utils = new Utils(this);
    startRegistration();
    isdriver = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.isDriver);
    list = new ListView(this);

    if (utils.getFromPreferences(Utils.UserName).isEmpty()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    } else {

        setPeopleList();

    }

}

void setPeopleList() {


    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    setContentView(list);
    getPeopleList();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

private void registerInBackground() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                utils.saveregid("regid_sender",regid);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = ex.getMessage();
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute : " + msg);

            if (!msg.equalsIgnoreCase("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE")) {

                Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("server_response", msg);
                msgObj.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(msgObj);

            } else {

                utils.showToast("Error : " + msg
                        + "\nPlease check your internet connection");

                hidePB();

            }
        }

        // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and
        // update the progress
        private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                String aResponse = msg.getData().getString(
                        "server_response");

                if ((null != aResponse)) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();");

                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                } else {

                }

            }
        };
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use
 * GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo
 * since the device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the
 * message using the 'from' address in the message.
 */
public void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

    Log.i(TAG, "sendRegistrationIdToBackend");

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // yahan reg id ki server webserivcice dalegi

                httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test5.luminativesolutions.com/cabbooking/ws/gcmdemo/save_reg_id.php");
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                        user_name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id", regid));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        responseHandler);
                Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);

                if (response != null) {

                    if (response
                            .equalsIgnoreCase("Username already registered")) {

                        utils.showToast("Username already registered");
                        utils.savePreferences("regid_sender",regid);

                        hidePB();



                    } else {
                        if (response
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("New Device Registered successfully")) {

                            utils.savePreferences(Utils.UserName, user_name);
                            // Persist the regID - no need to register
                            // again.
                            utils.savePreferences("regid_sender", regid);



                            utils.showToast("Device registration successful");

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    setPeopleList();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }


                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                hidePB();
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();

}

void getPeopleList() {

    hidePB();
    showPB("Getting People to Chat...");

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String response = "";

            try {

                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test5.luminativesolutions.com/cabbooking/ws/gcmdemo/get_people_list.php");
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                        utils.getFromPreferences(Utils.UserName)));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                Log.i(TAG, "USER :" + utils.getFromPreferences(Utils.UserName));
                Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + ex.getMessage());

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        utils.showToast("Server Not responding, Please check whether your server is running or not");
                    }
                });

            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("No People")) {
                peopleObjList = new ArrayList<PeopleObject>();
                // parse JSON here

                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String username = jsonObj.getString("username");
                        String reg_id = jsonObj.getString("reg_id");

                        PeopleObject p = new PeopleObject();
                        p.setPersonName(username);
                        p.setRegId(reg_id);
                        peopleObjList.add(p);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (peopleObjList.size() > 0) {

                    Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("people_list",
                            (Serializable) peopleObjList);
                    msgObj.setData(b);
                    handler.sendMessage(msgObj);

                }
            } else {
                hidePB();
                utils.showToast("No People registered for Chat...");
            }

        }

        // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and
        // update the progress
        private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<PeopleObject> peopleList = (ArrayList<PeopleObject>) msg
                        .getData().getSerializable("people_list");

                if (peopleList.size() > 0) {

                    ArrayAdapter<PeopleObject> adapter = new ListAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, peopleList);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {

                }

                hidePB();
            }
        };
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

void startRegistration() {

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
        // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
        Log.i(TAG, "Google Play Services OK");
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = utils.getRegistrationId();
        utils.saveregid("regid_sender",regid);
        /*if(isdriver.isChecked()){
            utils.savePreferences(user_name, regid);
            Log.d(TAG,utils.getFromPreferences(user_name));
        }*/
        System.out.println(regid);
        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Reg ID Not Empty");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }

}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No Google Play Services...Get it from the store.");
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void showPB(final String message) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pb = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pb.setMessage(message);
            pb.show();
        }
    });

}

void hidePB() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (pb != null && pb.isShowing())
                pb.dismiss();
        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnsave) {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        user_name = username.getText().toString().trim();
        utils.savePreferences("username",user_name);
        if (user_name.length() > 0) {

            Log.d(TAG, "startRegistration");

            showPB("Registering the device");

            startRegistration();

        } else {

            Log.d(TAG, "Username empty");

        }
    }
}
}
```

**Booking Activity**

```
public class BookingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
Utils utils;
Intent i;
static String TAG = "GCM DEMO";
String user_name;
String regid;

String SENDER_ID = "224163385438";
String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCL3REK_ONEgLdhcP8giso_5P6xWE3gUvA";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

    i = getIntent();

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"));
}

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        String message = b.getString("message");

        //Log.i(TAG, " Received in Activity " + message + ", NAME = "
          //      + i.getStringExtra("username"));


    }
};

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

public void onClick(final View view) {

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.booking)) {

        sendMessage();

       // startActivity(new Intent(BookingActivity.this,NotificationDailog.class));
        //clearMessageTextBox();

    }

}

public void sendMessage() {

    final String messageToSend = "Driver you are now booked by: "+i.getStringExtra("username");

    if (messageToSend.length() > 0) {

        Log.i(TAG, "sendMessage");

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httppost = new
                            HttpPost("http://www.test5.luminativesolutions.com/cabbooking/ws/gcmdemo/gcm_engine.php");
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                            messageToSend));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "registrationIDs", i.getStringExtra("regid")));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiKey",
                            API_KEY));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairs));
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                            responseHandler);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);
                    if (response.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Not Sent");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

    }

}
}
```

**Notification Dialog Activity**

```
public class NotificationDailog extends ActionBarActivity {


private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
String SENDER_ID = "224163385438";
String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCL3REK_ONEgLdhcP8giso_5P6xWE3gUvA";
private String regid;
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
private HttpPost httppost;
private String TAG = "GCM Demo";
private Utils utils;
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
private Context context = this;
private ProgressDialog pb;
private String regid_sender;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    utils = new Utils(this);
    regid_sender = utils.getregid("regid_sender");
    //regid_sender = BookingActivity.getregid();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_dailog);
    BookingActivity booking = new BookingActivity();
    registerReceiver(booking.broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED"));
}


public void Accept(View view) {


    //startRegistration();
    //getPeopleList();
    sendMessage();
    finish();
}

public void sendMessage() {

    final String messageToSend = "Driver Accepted your request";

    if (messageToSend.length() > 0) {

        Log.i(TAG, "sendMessage");

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httppost = new
                            HttpPost("http://www.test5.luminativesolutions.com/cabbooking/ws/gcmdemo/gcm_engine.php");
                    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
                            messageToSend));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "registrationIDs", regid_sender));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiKey",
                            API_KEY));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairs));
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                            responseHandler);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);
                    if (response.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Not Sent");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

    }
}

void showPB(final String message) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pb = new ProgressDialog(NotificationDailog.this);
            pb.setMessage(message);
            pb.show();
        }
    });

}

void hidePB() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (pb != null && pb.isShowing())
                pb.dismiss();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_notification_dailog, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The acknowledgement you get from the GCM service only tells you the message has been received by the GCM service, regardless to its being delivered to the application or not. You will get it even if the device on which the application is installed is turned off.

If you want to get an acknowledgement when the message is delivered to the application, you must call your server from your application when its receives the message. you can include some unique identifier in your message and send that identifier from your application to your server to acknowledge delivery.

Here's a Stack overflow ticket related to Acknowledgement: [Client(android application) acks for sent gcm messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548064/clientandroid-application-acks-for-sent-gcm-messages)